# Parsing a JMeter response (an XML-formatted .srx file)

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

I'm using JMeter to run a test where the response is returned as an XML-formatted .srx SPARQL file. The error I'm getting is:

```
2015/04/28 1:30:39 ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: Type=Val=false
    Tol=false org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;
    Content is not allowed in prolog.

2015/04/28 11:30:39 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: SAXException
    while processing (sparql/results/result/binding/literal) Content is not
    allowed in prolog.
```

I'm pretty new to JMeter. My guess is that my XPath Extractor somehow doing its magic in a place I'm not expecting. The XML file response looks like this (a snipplet from a file), without any space before or any extra characters:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
  <head>
    <variable name='p'/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name='p'>
        <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date'>1999-08-16</literal>
      </binding>
```

I set up my `XPathExtractor` this way:

```
Reference Name:Results
XPath query:sparql/results/result/binding/literal
default Value:Not Found
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the following approach:

1. In *user.properties* file (located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation) add the next line:

   ```
   xpath.namespace.config=my.properties
   ```
2. Create *my.properties* file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation and add the following line there:

   ```
   s=http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#
   ```
3. Configure your XPath Extractor the following way:

   - Check `Use Namespaces` box
   - Reference name: any variable name of your choice, i.e. `literal`
   - XPath Query: `//s:literal/text()`

In regards to your question: `Content is not allowed in prolog` message usually stands for not well-formed XML, my suggestion will be applicable to valid XML

References:

- [XPath Language Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml had a namespace without a prefix

```
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
```

while your XPATH is not considering the namespace .. 
you can choose one of two solutions

1. Either change namespace to be with a prefix and adjust your XPATH.
2. Or use this XPATH which considering the namespace

   /*[local-name()='sparql']/*[local-name()='results']/*[local-name()='result']/*[local-name()='binding']/*[local-name()='literal']

I hope this could help.

Comment: I copied and pasted the whole XPATH, but the error remains to be the same.

Comment: The error is:2015/04/28 12:35:55 ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: Type=Val=false Tol=false org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. 
2015/04/28 12:35:55 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.XPathExtractor: SAXException while processing (/*[local-name()='sparql']/*[local-name()='results']/*[local-name()='result']/*[local-name()='binding']/*[local-name()='literal'] ) Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: I'm seeing that my response data looks like this: BRTR       s       val        http://test.com/        test        !http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#        1999-08-16       date

Comment: I'm expecting to get an xml formated response, but the data looks unformated at all. It must be related to the error.

Comment: I think that you have something before **<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>**  may be new line or spaces please check.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace the XPath Extractor with the Regular Expression Extractor. Then, to find the string `1999-08-16 date`, I used the regex `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`. Somehow the date data comes on a separate line.